# AWS & Azure Regions & Availability Zone list

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I need to list all the regions and availability zones present in Azure and AWS. The documentations available on their websites don't seem to have the detailed list. How can I find the comprehensive list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the information you need using the CLI tools from AWS and Azure.

For AWS:

```
aws ec2 describe-regions
aws ec2 describe-availability-zones
```

References:

- Regions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html
- Availability zones: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-availability-zones.html

For Azure:

```
az account list-locations -o table
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-list-locations

Hope this helps.